# Is it possible to make Tridion Template Logging use Enterprise Library version 5.0?

Tags: 2011, templating

In Tridion 2011 SP1 templating, we are using Enterprise Library for logging information to a custom log file while publishing.

But unfortunately Tridion uses **[EntLib 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648527.aspx)** which is meant for `.NET Framework 2.0` and this doesn't support rolling file listener.

As per **[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc467894.aspx)**, **[EntLib 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648527.aspx)** is a *Retired Version*.

> **Is there a way to use latest EntLib versions 5.0?**

I know that **[log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)** can be used but I want to use default `EntLib` logging only.

Please suggest.

Comment: There probably is a way to load an alternative version of the EntLib with policy files, but that would likely make your entire Tridion system unsupported. Aside from that you'll have to wait for SDL to update them. Be sure to let SDL Customer Support know about your wish for this to happen.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Thanks Frank, will raise a request with support team.

Comment: Just checked the Tridion.ContentManager.Config of a Tridion 2013 server and it still uses version 2.0. There's probably a very good reason why it wasn't updated with 2013.

Comment: @NunoLinhares: ohh then what would that good reason behind still using version 2.0? :)

Comment: If I knew it, I would have shared it... the common reason for Tridion not to upgrade a dependency is because something else breaks if we do. You can always try changing T.CM.Config to use version 5 and see what happens...

Comment: @NunoLinhares: Actually i thought of trying it but am bit worried about license.

Comment: Indeed, the worst that can happen is that something stops working, and takes you, support and R&D a few weeks to figure out why it can't be reproduced...

Comment: @SivaCharan did you ever come to an answer for this question, either by changing your config or maybe the answer was just plain "no, not possible"? Would be worth posting that as an answer here and accepting it so we can use that for future reference.

Comment: @BartKoopman: Thanks. Today I have written my own rolling class which fullfill the criteria.

Comment: @BartKoopman: Now I can see rolling logs created

Comment: @SivaCharan thx for the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your inputs.

Today I finally decided to write my own Rolling Class and which uses internally `Entlib 2.0`

### Steps followed:

1. Create your own Rolling Class

   - RollingFileTraceListener
   - RollingFileTraceListenerData
2. Register your DLL into the GAC
3. Update the configuration with respective to your DLL
4. Restart the services

Now you will see rolling logs are created.